# Issues with ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm trying to write a program that asks you to click on a button to generate a random number and then makes the user try to guess what that number is.

Right now I'm working on getting a button click to generate a random number and to tell the user that the random number has been generated through a JTextPane. For whatever reason this part of the code doesn't seem to be executing correctly.

I have already instanced the object in the main class and I've added an actionlistener to the button. I have no idea what's causing this not to work appropriately:

```
package GUIs;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Principal extends JFrame {
//Elements
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField attemptField;
private JTextPane hint;
private JButton btnGenerate;
private JButton btnEnter;

//Events
private GenerateRandomNumber genRanNum;

//Misc variables
int ranNum = 1;
private JTextField textField;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Principal frame = new Principal();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Principal() {

    //Generates JPanel
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    //Generates text field where the user will write the number
    attemptField = new JTextField();
    attemptField.setBounds(130, 59, 130, 26);
    contentPane.add(attemptField);
    attemptField.setColumns(10);

    //Generates the hint
    hint = new JTextPane();
    hint.setBackground(SystemColor.window);
    hint.setText("First, generate a new number!");
    hint.setBounds(130, 110, 192, 19);
    contentPane.add(hint);

    //Generates the button that should call for the creation of the new number
    btnGenerate = new JButton("Generate number");
    btnGenerate.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    btnGenerate.setBounds(165, 153, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnGenerate);
    btnGenerate.addActionListener(genRanNum);

    //Generates button that will be used to enter the number
    btnEnter = new JButton("Enter");
    btnEnter.setBounds(269, 59, 58, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnEnter);
}

public class GenerateRandomNumber implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        ranNum = (int) (Math.random() * 101);

        hint.setText("The number has been created!");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: A [typical result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Ypw.png) of *not* using layout managers (a broken GUI). **My usual copy/paste comment:** Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private GenerateRandomNumber genRanNum;
```

Your random number generator is null. I don't see where you ever create an instance of it.

```
btnGenerate.addActionListener(genRanNum);
```

The above statement does nothing because the variable is null. (ie. no ActionListener has been added to the button)

I don't even know how your GenerateRandomNumber class would compile because it doesn't have access to the "hint" variable of your "Principal" class.

Don't make the GenerateRandomNumber class a public class. Instead make it an inner class of the "Principal" class.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for an example showing how to use inner classes. Note you can even use an `Action` instead of an ActionListener.

Comment: Yeah, I did a pretty terrible job in how I posted this. It is an internal class. I'm going to edit the post.

Comment: *"The above statement does nothing because the variable is null."* Huh .. I'd have hoped adding an `null` `ActionListener` would throw an NPE. But ..no.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes, ultimately there is a check if the listener is null and returns right away. Although there is a comment in the source code saying: *In an ideal world, we would do an assertion here to help developers know they are probably doing something wrong.* Well at least they though about it. lol